# Save and Add integer value in UserDefaults and retrieve after adding the value

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults, swiftyuserdefaults

I can save and retrieve deleted mails number (such as like Integer value) in `UserDefaults`. Suppose if I deleted some more mails then I have to add/increase that saved `UserDefaults` value and if I retrieve it should come total deleted mails number. ->> Here `numEmails` is deleted mails number(Integer).

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(numEmails, forKey: "NumberofMailsDeleted") //Saving
var numMailsDeleted = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "NumberofMailsDeleted") //Retriving
print("I've deleted \(numMailsDeleted) mails") //Printing`
```

I will explain this scenario with other example ->> I want to save vehicles incoming (number of vehicles inside) into the parking area (i.e. the `UserDefaults` saved value is changing according to the cars incoming). If I retrieve it should come updated value of incoming don't think about outgoing, I don't need outgoing

Comment: What will be the issue in that you are saving and retrieving without any issue right?

Comment: hi @GaneshManickam, i can save one value but how i can  add/increase it's value if i delete more mails after some time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the set(Int, forKey: String) method of UserDefaults:

```
//Get
let deletedMailsCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "NumberofMailsDeleted")
//Update deletedMails count
deletedMailsCount += 1;
//Set
UserDefaults.standard.set(deletedMailsCount, forKey: "NumberofMailsDeleted")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: Indra Mohan thanks, it's constantly increaring to 1 but i want to get everytime value from numEmails varaiable.

Comment: I added that code just for your understanding. Remove that part and put your own logic to calculate the deleted emails.

Answer (score 1):

```
var deletedEmail: Int { get { return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "emailsDeleted") } set { UserDefaults.standard.set( newValue forKey:"emailsDeleted")} }
```

Using computed property you can simplify it to something like this.
newValue is a keyword you can use inside set property. Do not declare newValue !!.
Just try the code and let me know.